# WireShark / How to save only packets captured by filter without stoppinng current capturing process?

Tags: wireshark

How to save only packets captured by filter without stopping current capturing process in WireShark 2.2.2 - it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

You can try the following trick to get capture data without capture stopping though, and possibly hack together a solution that does what you want:

In **Capture Options** set **Create a new file automatically after N secs**.

You'll get a piece of your trace every N seconds then without stopping the capture, and you can merge/filter/save these pieces.